# Error in TORA while implementing in ns2

Tags: algorithm, ns2, tora

When I run the code

http://wpage.unina.it/marcello.caleffi/ns2/tora.cc and

http://wpage.unina.it/marcello.caleffi/ns2/tora.h

The error I get is

```
invalid command name "int"
while executing
"int hdr_tora::offset_"
(file "tora.cc" line 18)
```

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

---

Well, you are not supposed to "run the code".

And : files.cc cannot be compiled individually in ns2.

---

Build example : tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

cd ns-allinone-2.35/

patch -p0 < tora_ns235.patch

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNQXhib1BhRlVSSm8/view?usp=sharing

./install

---

Tora examples : tora-files+examples.tar.gz

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNQ2hYb0xPcmdlWU0/view?usp=sharing

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)

Comment: I have installed ns2.

Comment: What should I do now to get the output? I'm new to it. I googled it but could not understand the steps. Please can you explain